# Laplace transform of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question, laplace-transform

> Solve for $y(x)$ given: $$y"-y'-6y=0$$ with $y(0)=6$ and $y'(0)=13$ by using Laplace transforms.

---

I tried solving it but I am getting the wrong answer. Please help me with this one.

Comment: Maybe if you post your solution we can tell you where you are wrong :)

Comment: I scribbled it on a piece of paper 

Comment: Doesn't matter. You can upload photos.

Comment: Don't have enough reputation

Comment: Where are you stuck Steve ?

Comment: Stuck after substituting the values

Comment: So, after substituting values, you should have solved for the Laplace transform of $y$ and gotten a rational expression that is a linear divided by a quadratic.  What rational expression did you get?

Comment: Thank you @Aryadeva

Comment: you're welcomed Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y"-y'-6y=0$$
Apply Laplace Transform:
$$s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)-(sY(s)-y(0))-6Y(s)=0$$
$$Y(s)(s^2-s-6)=sy(0)+y'(0)-y(0)$$
Apply initial conditions:
$$Y(s)(s^2-s-6)=6s+7$$
$$\implies Y(s)=\dfrac {6s+7}{s^2-s-6}$$
$$\implies Y(s)=\dfrac {6s+7}{(s+2)(s-3)}$$
Is it here that you are stuck, Steve ?
$$ Y(s)=\dfrac {6s+7}{(s+2)(s-3)}$$
Decompose the fraction into simple fractions:
$$ Y(s)=\dfrac {1}{(s+2)}+\dfrac {5}{(s-3)}$$
Apply inverse Laplace transform now. You have a table here [Laplace Transform Table](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/laplace_table.pdf)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I'm stuck after getting Y(s). I need to find the Laplace inverse of Y(s) according to my teacher

Comment: You need to decompose the fraction into simple elements @SteveBobyGeorge

Comment: Yes the decomposition part

Comment: I decomposed the fraction now take inverse laplace transform look at the table on inverse laplace transform @SteveBobyGeorge

Comment: I added a link to the table of laplace Transform... @SteveBobyGeorge

Comment: Then the final answer will be e^-2t + 5e^3t

Comment: Yes Steve that's correct..  @SteveBobyGeorge